# Error React Native Typescript : Element type 'MutableRefObject<never[]>'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, ref

I have this error with my code :
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'any' can't be used to index type 'MutableRefObject<never[]>'

Howether I can't resolve it by changing my items.

Here is my code:

```
const Comp = (props: { items: any[] }) => {
  const refs = useRef([]);

  return (
    <>
      {props.items.map((i) => (
        <div key={i} ref={(el) => (refs[i] = el)}>
          {i}
        </div>
      ))}
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: You need to define the refs with a type. Try with `const refs = useRef<HTMLDivElement []>([]);`

Comment: The error is still the same : Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'any' can't be used to index type 'MutableRefObject<HTMLDivElement[]>'.

Comment: For `refs[i]`, do you want to use index instead of actual item. If yes, add the index property in map method and use it.